# Export from EXCEL into MSSQL based on the colour of cells

Tags: sql-server, excel

Is there any chance to import xls or csv file to MSSQL database with colour filter?
I've got cells coloured and let's say I only need those that're red.

Comment: Colour isn't data, it's styling

Comment: I'm very confident in saying no. Openrowset cannot see the setting of a cell. if you need to filter on colour, I suggest adding additional column(s) with the extra information; then you can filter on those.

Comment: Why don't you filter it first in Excel and remove any data you don't want to import?

Comment: I thought so but needed to be sure it's not only me :)
@SeanLange there're many files so it's pretty crappy work.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you there. Using coloring to indicate a status is a pretty crappy way of handling information.

Comment: Sadly it's the favourite way of accountants ;) Thanks for info.

Comment: Accountants should use conditional formatting. However, because accountants won't likely use it, I suggest you to program a c# console app that uses ClosedXml to read the excel files then use SqlBulkCopy to insert into a SQL Server table.

Comment: Don't need the openrowset reference.  Modify title to make it clear